# HttpURLConnection showing incorrect status

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use Selenium Webdriver to check if every link on my website/cms is working by checking http status. To do it, I'm using HttpURLConnection class in Selenium Webdriver. Here is the code I'm executing:

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class checkingLinks {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.get("link_to_cms");

    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("my_login");
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("my_passwod");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']")).click();

    List<WebElement> links=driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

    System.out.println("Total links are "+links.size());

    for(int i=0;i<links.size();i++)
    {

        WebElement ele= links.get(i);

        String url=ele.getAttribute("href");

        verifyLinkActive(url);

    }

}

public static void verifyLinkActive(String linkUrl)
{
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL(linkUrl);

        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnect=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

        httpURLConnect.setConnectTimeout(3000);

        httpURLConnect.connect();

        System.out.println(linkUrl+" - "+httpURLConnect.getResponseCode());


    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

}
```

The problem is that in results all links are getting http status 200, but I know that few of them are with http status 500. Do you maybe know how it is possible? Have I made a mistake in above code that makes false results?

Comment: Honestly I don't see any error in your code. Everything looks perfect. In-case its a public URL can you share the URL which is fetching incorrect results?

Comment: @Dev Unfortunately, it's not a public URL - CMS is visible only at my office network. So in your opinion, the code itself is a proper one? Good to know :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that your `HttpURLConnection` sends a HTTP request at all.  It just opens a connection.

Also, the cookies you receive when you authenticate (login) need to be sent as headers in your subsequent requests.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So what do you suggest to fix/add to my code to get things working as it should?